# I want to be able to add items from a DataTemplate (CollectionView) into an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add some Addons to my Booking Checkout page,

[Screenshot of Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stm9c.png)

The Addons are displayed in a CollectionView, based on what addons are available for that office they are trying to book:

**BookingInfo.xaml**

```
<CollectionView x:Name="AddonSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding OfficeAddons}" SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <Label Text="No Addons for this Office" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImgName}" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Micro"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Label x:Name="AddonQuantity" Text="{Binding SelectedQuantity}"/>
                                <Stepper x:Name="AddonQuantityStepper" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Quantity}" Increment="1" Value="{Binding StepperValue}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />                            
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

The issue I have is that I want to create an observable collection of Addon to my Booking Model, to record what addons and quantity the user has added to their booking.

My goal is to foreach loop in every datatemplate 'stacklayout' created in my collection view, check if stepper value > 0 and add the Binding ImgName, Name, Price and StepperValue (Quantity) to my new observablecollection.

This is what I have so far in my SaveBooking() in the ViewModel fro my BookingInfo.

**BookingInfoVM.cs**

```
 public int SaveBooking()
    {
        int addstatus = 0;

        double numhours = CalculateBookingHourLenght();
        bool isActive = IsBookingActive();

        Models.Booking newbooking = new Models.Booking();
        ...

        // Addons
        

        foreach (Models.Addon OfficeAddon in OfficeAddons)
            // foreach (StackLayout Data in CollectView:AddonSelection)
        {
            // if steppervalue >=1 then ...
            newbooking.BookedAddons.Add(new Models.Addon
            {
                ImgName = OfficeAddon.ImgName,
                Name = OfficeAddon.Name,
                Price = OfficeAddon.Price,
                Quantity = StepperValue //Stuck
            });
        }
        globalref.TempBooking = newbooking;

        //addstatus = DBInstance.AddBooking(newbooking);

        return addstatus;
    }
```

Booking Model
**Booking.cs**

```
public class Booking
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int BID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start_datetime { get; set; }
    //public TimeSpan Start_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime End_datetime { get; set; }
    //public TimeSpan End_time { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public double Total_hours { get; set; }
    public int NumGuests { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public string TimePeriod { get; set; }
    //Payment



    // Foregin key to Booked Office
    public int OID { get; set; }
    public int HID { get; set; }
    public string OName { get; set; }
    public string OLocation { get; set; }

    
    // list of booked selected addons
    public ObservableCollection<Models.Addon> BookedAddons { get; set; }

    //public double TotalAddonPrice { get; set; }

    // Foregin key to Guest User
    public int UID { get; set; }
    public string GName { get; set; }


    public double OfficePrice { get; set; } // Office Hourly * Total_hours
    public double ServiceFee { get; set; } // set equal to (addon price + office price) * 0.15 
    public double FinalPrice { get; set; } // equal to office + addon + service 

}
```

Addon Model **Addon.cs**

```
    public class Addon
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int AID { get; set; }
    [Unique]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string ImgName { get; set; }

    // link to Office by ID
    public int OID { get; set; }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I need help with creating the foreach loop to iterate through each stacklayout in my collection view, to then save the values of the labels to an observablecollection of addons in the booking.

Comment: What do you need help with?  You have not described any specific problem you’re encountering with this code

Comment: @Jason I need help making the loop save the steppervalue for each addon with the rest of the data from that addon in the observable collection<Addon> in the booking.

Comment: your Stepper is bound to `StepperValue` but there is no property with that name in your model.  Wouldn't it make sense to bind it to the `Quantity` property instead?

Comment: I am reluctant to do this, as when my collectionview loads, it uses the quantity to set the maximum. the issue is that in my foreach, it will not recognize my get or set for steppervalue = OfficeAddon.SteooerValue

Comment: then add a `StepperValue` property to your model